# Multiline filter with logstash not working as expected

Tags: multiline, logstash, logstash-grok

I was playing around with logstash and wanted to try the multiline filter. I'm trying to parse a single file which can has multiline content in it. I'm using the multiline filter but it does not work the way it should. I have the following content in the file.

```
2014-10-11 10:10:10 xxxx yyyy
2013-09-12 11:11:11 aaaa bbbb
2012-01-01 10:10:10 cccc dddd
2011-10-12 01:01:01 mmmm Nan
```

**Grok-pattern used**

```
CUSTOMTIME %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}
```

I'm using the following config file in logstash

```
input {
    file{
        path => "/Users/akshayanilkapoor/Kumo/logs/akshay"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^.*"
            what => "previous"
            negate => true
        }
    }
   stdin{
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{CUSTOMTIME}"
            what => "previous"
            negate => true
        }
     }
}
filter {
   grok {
        patterns_dir => "./patterns"
        match => ["message", "%{CUSTOMTIME:date1} %{GREEDYDATA:lumber-type} %{GREEDYDATA:lumber-desc}"]
        }
    }

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

When i copy paste the data shown above from the *stdin*, it works as expected i.e. it displays the output with the message containing all the the events in the file. When i pass the same with the file it outputs a different message for every log entry i.e. I get 4 different log events (which is not what i desire)

Note: I have tried using the following options along with the multiline,

1. (?m) multi-line mode in grok and that too does not help in any way.
2. Also used mutate filter to replace "\n" with " " and parse it with grok.

I think there is a very silly mistake that I have been making or i'm understanding the filter incorrectly to be implemented. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the negate option of the multiline codec incorrectly as i expected :p This is the config file I used for the the config to work incase it helps someone.

```
input {
    file{
        path => "/Users/akshayanilkapoor/Kumo/logs/akshay"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^[0-9]"
            what => "previous"
            #negate => true
        }
    }
   stdin{
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^[a-z]"
            what => "previous"
            negate => "true"
        }
     }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "(?m)%{RSMROLLBACKTIME:date1} %{GREEDYDATA:lumber-type} %{GREEDYDATA:lumber-desc}"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```